# Ansible - best method to copy results of json_query to file

Tags: ansible

Below is an excerpt from a playbook that queries a REST service, stores the results, and displays to the screen via the debug module. What is the best way to write the result to a file with the desired format?

```
vars:
  jquery: "json[].{File: filename, Path: filepath, Size: size}"

uri:
  url: "https://somewhere.com/subscriptions"
register: "subscriptions"

debug:
  msg: "{{ subscriptions | json_query(jquery) }}"

copy:
  content: "{{ subscriptions | json_query(jquery) }}"
  dest: "./subscriptions.txt"
```

The debug output looks like the below:

```
{ File: "afile",
  Path: "somepath/afile",
  Size: "9999.0"
},
{ File: "bfile",
  Path: "somepath/bfile",
  Size: "9999.0"
}
```

Using the copy module the results are all ran together. What is the best way to preserve the formatting of the debug ouput? Bonus points if the "{}," characters can be removed.

I'm assuming the correct answer involves the use of templating?

Thank you.

Comment: Check the [`to_json` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest answer is probably:

```
copy:
  content: "{{ subscriptions | json_query(jquery) | to_nice_json }}"
  dest: "./subscriptions.txt"
```

This will produce nicely formatted JSON output. Because your result is a list, the output file will look like:

```
[
    {
        "File": "afile",
        "Path": "somepath/afile",
        "Size": "9999.0"
    },
    {
        "File": "bfile",
        "Path": "somepath/bfile",
        "Size": "9999.0"
    }
]
```

If you want output that isn't valid JSON, you'll probably have to use
the `template` module to produce it yourself.

---

If you want your output to look like this:

```
File: afile,
Path: somepath/afile
Size: 9999.0

File: bfile,
Path: somepath/bfile
Size: 9999.0
```

You might write:

```
copy:
  content: |
    {% for item in items %}
    File: {{ item.File }}
    Path: {{ item.Path }}
    Size: {{ item.Size }}

    {% endfor %}
  dest: "./subscriptions.txt"
  vars:
    items: "{{ subscriptions | json_query(jquery) }}"
```

...but ideally you would use the `template` module instead of
embedding the template in the `copy` module like this (that's just a matter of moving the content of the `content` key in this example into a file, and using that as the `src` of the `template` task).

Comment: Appreciate this. Can you provide a brief example of how I would accomplish via template?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Greatly appreciated!